# How to get the structure of a specific widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, hierarchy

I want to get the structure of a specific widget to build a Tree-view hierarchy of that widget.
For example, if I have a widget like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Text("Pressed below button"),
       FlatButton(
         child: Text('Print'),
         onPressed: (){},
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

So how can I get a structure like this:

- Container

  - Column

    - Text
    - FlatButton

      - Text

Edit: I want to build the structure above into a tree-view and show it to the user. I've found a package to build the tree (tree_view or flutter_treeview). However, I need the structure of widget, or a variable that contains the structure to use with the package. Any suggestion or approach?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what Flutter Outline and Flutter Inspector does. Check [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector) for more information.

[image]

Comment: yes, I do want a structure like this. However, as I just update my post, I want to show it to the user, so how can I get this as a variable in code?